# How do I set an initial value for a date in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

So I have researched this for several days and I am trying to put an initial value to a date.  It needs to be 4 weeks from yesterday so the model has this in it:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date Only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Starting Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-29);
```

This is the code for the view:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
```

Yet, whether I have the default date in the model or not, the view yields this:

[image]

I want it to be changeable but this is the initial value I am trying to deploy.

I have also tried this in the view. No Change.

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "datepicker", @Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-29) } })
```

Comment: You will have post the action too

Comment: you can do it using jquery on page-load you have to call this $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass it using Razor, [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, DateTime.Today.AddDays(-29), new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
```

Comment: I could not get this to work.  It was too many operands in the signature for EditorFor.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).